# What technology should I use to allow my Windows Service or Web Service (written in C#) publish it's progress and status?

Tags: c#, service, communication, named-pipes

The requirement: 
My [windows/web] service in C# 3.5 periodically has something to say about its state. It could be a progress status, log entry, error or warning, or signal of data availability.
Client applications are on the same network, and they would like to learn about some of these messages.
Clients start and stop randomly, largely outside of my control. 
Clients are written in C#, C++ and even Delphi.
Database connection that can support storing my service's messages may not be available.

I would like my service to publish its messages (text-based protocol) for subscribers to be able to see and react to. I don't want to bother with how many clients are connected, or are there clients at all.

I was looking into named pipes, regular TCP/IP, semaphores, but I cannot seem to find anything that fits the bill.

Currently I'm forced to store a file on the network that is being currently updated, but it's not clean, and requires clients to have access to a network share.

Comment: Why not publish the information you want to make available through an http based interface? That's about as text based as you can get and pretty much everything on the planet will be able to read from it - including humans :)

Comment: I tried HTTP, but having multiple sessions concurrently add their event info to a common publishing pool is hard. I have to resort to the file system again. I'm looking for something that would be automatically synchronized, like named pipes, but not necessary requiring clients to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use WCF for this.

WCF can handle named pipes, TCP/IP and it can do windows and Web services.

You can have a look here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [OWIN](http://owin.org/) project and the [Kayak](https://github.com/kayak/kayak) implementation.

It will allow you to run your own in-process web server.